# What happens when you disable rich text format in Exchange 2010?

Tags: exchange-2010

I've read this article on how to disable rtf for remote domains in Exchange 2010.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310786.aspx

My question is if I do disable rtf emails using this method, what happens when a user tries to send email in rtf format? Does the email get converted to plain text or html or does it get blocked completely?

Comment: Test on yourself and find out?  I believe it works by disabling the option and selecting/assigning an encoding-type to the messages, but I'm not actually sure about that (so I deleted my answer).

Comment: As a side effect, the world will be saved. :)